# Number of $(n-1)-$cycles in $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutation-cycles

In a solution to an old exam, it is claimed that for $n$ even, the number of $(n-1)$-cycles in $S_n$ is precisely $\frac{n!}{n-1} = n(n-2)!$. I understand the rest of the solution, but this part is the only part that is not explained, and of course the only part that eludes me..

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this using the orbit-stabiliser theorem and the action of $S_n$ on itself by conjugacy. For $c \in S_n$ the size of the conjugacy class $c^{S_n}$ is $|S_n|/|\mathrm{Stab}_{S_n} (c)|$ where $\mathrm{Stab}_{S_n}(c) = \{h \in S_n : hc = ch \}$.

Picking the particular $(n-1)$-cycle $c = (1,2,\ldots, n-1)$, we have $hc = ch$ if and only if $c^h = c$, so if and only if

$$(1,2,\ldots,n-1) = (1^h, 2^h, \ldots, (n-1)^h).$$

If $1^h = k$ then we must have $2^h = k+1$, $3^h = k+2$, and so on, wrapping around at $n-1$. So $h = (1,2,\ldots, n-1)^{k-1}$ and $h$ is a power of $c$. Since $c$ clearly commutes with itself, we get that $\mathrm{Stab}_{S_n} (c)$ is generated by $c$. Hence $|\mathrm{Stab}_{S_n}(c)| = |\langle c \rangle| = n-1$.

By the first paragraph it follows that the number of $(n-1)$-cycles is $n! /(n-1) = n(n-2)!$. Note this doesn't need that $n$ is even, only that $n \ge 2$.

Answer (score 5):

To see why the number of $(n-1)$-cycles in $S_n$ is $n(n-2)!$, observe that you have $n$ choices for the number in $\{1,\dots, n\}$ which will not appear in the $(n-1)$-cycle, and that if you write the $(n-1)$-cycle so that the smallest number appears first (i.e., for $n=4$ you would write $(132)$ rather than $(213)$) then there are $(n-2)!$ possible orderings of the remaining numbers which will appear in the cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Since we want a $n-1$ cycle that means one element among $1,2,3, \ldots ,n$ will be fixed. That element can be chosen in $n$ ways. The remaining $n-1$ elements can be permuted in $(n-1)!$ ways, however each cyclical shift produces the same permutation function (i.e. if $(a_1 \, a_2 \ldots \,a_{n-1})$ is a permutation function, then $(a_2 \, a_3 \ldots \,a_{n-1}\, \color{blue}{a_1})$ is the same permutation function) so we have to factor out $n-1$ to avoid overcounting. This means the number of $n-1$ cycles are
$$n\frac{(n-1)!}{n-1}=n(n-2)!$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the symmetric group $S_n$ and let $1 \leq m \leq n$. Then the number of $m$-cycles is $\frac{n!}{m(n-m)!}$:

There are $\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}$ possible permutations of $m$ elements from possible $n$ elements ($n$ choices for the first one, $n-1$ for the next one etc.). Since every $m$-cycle can be permuted $m$ times cyclically to get the same cycle, we will get $\frac{n!}{m(n-m)!}$ $m$-cycles.

Now let $m = n-1$. This yields $\frac{n!}{n-1} = n \cdot (n-2)!$ many $(n-1)$-cycles.

Answer (score 0):

There are ${}^{n-1}P_n=\dfrac {n!}1=n!$ $(n-1)$-cycles that can be formed.

However,  we divide by $n-1$, because you can cyclically permute a $k$ cycle $k$ ways and get the same cycle.

So, $\dfrac {n!}{n-1}=n(n-2)!$.